# Group by variables to create new column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by

The first table is the data at hand and I am looking to create table-2 using it. In the second table, value is the important variable that needs to be created. It is created using first table. We group by user and video and create a new variable value which depends on following:
If it’s the first row it’s automatically assigned a value 0, for other rows we look at previous rows. If rows before had only a no on the happy column a value of 1 is assigned. If  rows before had only a yes on the happy column a value of 2 is assigned. If rows before have both a yes and no in the happy column, a value of 3 is assigned.

| User | Video | Comment | Happy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | V1 | 1 | No |
| a | V1 | 2 | Yes |
| a | V1 | 3 | No |
| a | V2 | 4 | Yes |
| a | V3 | 5 | No |
| a | V3 | 6 | No |
| a | V4 | 7 | Yes |
| a | V4 | 8 | No |
| a | V4 | 9 | No |
| b | V1 | 10 | No |
| b | V1 | 11 | No |
| b | V5 | 12 | Yes |
| b | V5 | 13 | Yes |
| b | V5 | 14 | No |

```
df <- tibble(
  User = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"),
  Video = c("V1", "V1", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V3", "V4", "V4", "V4", "V1", "V1", "V5", "V5", "V5", "V5"),
  Comment = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15),
  Happy = c("No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No"))
```

Table-2

| User | Video | Comment | Happy | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | V1 | 1 | No | 0 |
| a | V1 | 2 | Yes | 1 |
| a | V1 | 3 | No | 3 |
| a | V2 | 4 | Yes | 0 |
| a | V3 | 5 | No | 0 |
| a | V3 | 6 | No | 1 |
| a | V4 | 7 | Yes | 0 |
| a | V4 | 8 | No | 2 |
| a | V4 | 9 | No | 3 |
| b | V1 | 10 | No | 0 |
| b | V1 | 11 | No | 1 |
| b | V5 | 12 | Yes | 0 |
| b | V5 | 13 | Yes | 2 |
| b | V5 | 14 | No | 2 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the code below, which compares the number of previous reviews and the number that were happy, and classifies the result. I've used data.table here.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)    

df[, let(cum_reviews = seq_len(.N)-1,
         cum_happy = shift(cumsum(Happy=="Yes"))), 
  keyby=.(User, Video)]

df[, Value := fcase(cum_reviews==0, 0,
                    cum_happy==0, 1,
                    cum_happy==cum_reviews, 2,
                    cum_happy<cum_reviews, 3)]  

print(df)

Key: <User, Video>
      User  Video Comment  Happy cum_reviews cum_happy Value
    <char> <char>   <num> <char>       <num>     <int> <num>
 1:      a     V1       1     No           0        NA     0
 2:      a     V1       2    Yes           1         0     1
 3:      a     V1       3     No           2         1     3
 4:      a     V2       4    Yes           0        NA     0
 5:      a     V3       5     No           0        NA     0
 6:      a     V3       6     No           1         0     1
 7:      a     V4       7    Yes           0        NA     0
 8:      a     V4       8     No           1         1     2
 9:      a     V4       9     No           2         1     3
10:      b     V1      10     No           0        NA     0
11:      b     V1      11     No           1         0     1
12:      b     V5      12    Yes           0        NA     0
13:      b     V5      13    Yes           1         1     2
14:      b     V5      14     No           2         2     2
15:      b     V5      15     No           3         2     3
>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first create a column (i.e. my `Happy2`) that concatenates the `Happy` column in a rolling fashion (by `sapply`), which helps to determine what has happened in previous rows excluding the present row. Then use `case_when` to assign `value`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  mutate(Happy2 = sapply(seq_along(Happy), \(x) paste0(Happy[1:x - 1], collapse = "")),
         value = case_when(row_number() == 1 ~ 0,
                           grepl("YesNo|NoYes", Happy2) ~ 3,
                           !grepl("Yes", Happy2) ~ 1,
                           !grepl("No", Happy2) ~ 2),
         .by = c(User, Video)) |> 
  select(-Happy2)

# A tibble: 15 × 5
   User  Video Comment Happy value
   <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1 a     V1          1 No        0
 2 a     V1          2 Yes       1
 3 a     V1          3 No        3
 4 a     V2          4 Yes       0
 5 a     V3          5 No        0
 6 a     V3          6 No        1
 7 a     V4          7 Yes       0
 8 a     V4          8 No        2
 9 a     V4          9 No        3
10 b     V1         10 No        0
11 b     V1         11 No        1
12 b     V5         12 Yes       0
13 b     V5         13 Yes       2
14 b     V5         14 No        2
15 b     V5         15 No        3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lag(cumsum(Happy == "Yes" #or "No"))` as indexes, then use `case_when`.

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
    mutate(cum_happy = lag(cumsum(Happy == "Yes")),
           cum_unhappy = lag(cumsum(Happy == "No")),
           .by = c(User, Video)) |>
    mutate(Value = case_when(row_number() == 1 ~ 0,
                             cum_happy == 0 ~ 1,
                             cum_unhappy == 0 ~ 2,
                             .default = 3),
           .by = c(User, Video),
           .keep = "unused")

# A tibble: 15 × 5
   User  Video Comment Happy Value
   <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1 a     V1          1 No        0
 2 a     V1          2 Yes       1
 3 a     V1          3 No        3
 4 a     V2          4 Yes       0
 5 a     V3          5 No        0
 6 a     V3          6 No        1
 7 a     V4          7 Yes       0
 8 a     V4          8 No        2
 9 a     V4          9 No        3
10 b     V1         10 No        0
11 b     V1         11 No        1
12 b     V5         12 Yes       0
13 b     V5         13 Yes       2
14 b     V5         14 No        2
15 b     V5         15 No        3
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some fun doing this. Perhaps a source to collect some ideas for a reshaped and more concise version

```r
l = split(df, list(df$User, df$Video))
l = l[sapply(l, \(x) dim(x)[1L]) > 0L]

lapply(l, \(j) sapply(seq(nrow(j)), \(i) {
  ifelse(all(lag(j[["Happy"]])[1L:i] == "No", na.rm = TRUE), 1L, 
         ifelse(all(lag(j[["Happy"]])[1L:i] == "Yes", na.rm =TRUE), 2L, 3L))})) |>
  lapply(\(x) { y = c(0L, x); y[-length(y)]}) |> 
  unlist() |>  
  cbind(do.call("rbind", l), "Value" = _) |> 
  { \(new) new[with(new, order(User)), ] }()
#>       User Video Comment Happy Value
#> a.V11    a    V1       1    No     0
#> a.V12    a    V1       2   Yes     1
#> a.V13    a    V1       3    No     3
#> a.V2     a    V2       4   Yes     0
#> a.V31    a    V3       5    No     0
#> a.V32    a    V3       6    No     1
#> a.V41    a    V4       7   Yes     0
#> a.V42    a    V4       8    No     2
#> a.V43    a    V4       9    No     3
#> b.V11    b    V1      10    No     0
#> b.V12    b    V1      11    No     1
#> b.V51    b    V5      12   Yes     0
#> b.V52    b    V5      13   Yes     2
#> b.V53    b    V5      14    No     2
#> b.V54    b    V5      15    No     3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**Data**

```
df <- dplyr::tibble(
  User = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"),
  Video = c("V1", "V1", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V3", "V4", "V4", "V4", "V1", "V1", "V5", "V5", "V5", "V5"),
  Comment = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15),
  Happy = c("No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No"))
```